# Inserting multiple query result in to mysql table

Tags: mysql

I want to insert the following query result in to a new table. Please help me ho to do that.
Here is the query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT item_name as 'Item Name', item_type as 'Item Type', 
                           (SUM(item_qty)-(
                                 SELECT SUM(srv_qty) FROM jos_sales 
                                 WHERE item_name=srv_name)
                           ) AS Balance,
                           (SUM(item_qty)-(
                                 SELECT SUM(srv_qty) FROM jos_sales 
                                 WHERE item_name=srv_name)
                           ) * item_price AS 'Total Cost' 
                       FROM jos_item c GROUP BY item_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

As easy as use [insert ...select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
 ("Insert into your_table ( columns )
   SELECT item_name as 'Item Name', item_type as 'Item Type', 
       (SUM(item_qty)-(
       ...
 ");
```

Comment: Thank U for your immediate response. I have tried it but it doesn't work. The query runs well but when I want to insert the result in a new table having the appropriate columns it doesn't insert any thing. Can you please check the query and help me?

Comment: Ok it works directly on mysql but it has an error on php I'll try to find a solution. Thank U

Answer (score 0):

First create a new table which matches the column structure of your query, and then prepend your query with `INSERT INTO newtable ...` - you can insert the results directly into the table without running them through PHP or another retrieval interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT... SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO newTable(item_name, item_type, Balance, TotalCost)
SELECT item_name as 'Item Name', item_type as 'Item Type', 
                           (SUM(item_qty)-(
                                 SELECT SUM(srv_qty) FROM jos_sales 
                                 WHERE item_name=srv_name)
                           ) AS Balance,
                           (SUM(item_qty)-(
                                 SELECT SUM(srv_qty) FROM jos_sales 
                                 WHERE item_name=srv_name)
                           ) * item_price AS 'Total Cost' 
                       FROM jos_item c GROUP BY item_name
```

Comment: Thank U for your immediate response. I have tried it but it doesn't work. The query runs well but when I want to insert the result in a new table having the appropriate columns it doesn't insert any thing. Can you please check the query and help me?

Comment: it works directly on mysql but it has an error on php I'll try to find a solution. Thank U